# Recorrer un diccionario entre dos límites

Tags: python, python-3.x, diccionarios

Quiero recorrer un diccionario y obtener los valores 750, 1300 y 2100:

```
niveles = {
       0: 0,
       1: 50,  2: 100, 3: 200, 4: 200, 5: 400,
       6: 750, 7: 1300, 8: 2100, 9: 3100, 10: 4650,
       11: 6500, 12: 8800, 13: 11600, 14: 14950, 15: 18900,
       16: 23500, 17: 28800, 18: 34850, 19: 41700, 20: 49400
      }

for key in niveles[5:8]:
    print(key)
```

Me devuelve este error:

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: traduce tu pregunta, esta es la versión de SO en español

Comment: No entiendo lo que necesitas hacer, no se inglés, solo veo en tu post que quieres hacer un recorrido pero no se cual es tu pregunta principal. Por favor, si vas a postearlo en stackoverflow español entonces haz el post en español por lo menos.

Comment: Hola Juan Esteban, bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad. Y por último pero no menos importante **Como crear un [mcve]**

Comment: Traduce el titulo por favor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que estas intentando hacer un `slice` como el que se hace con una lista, pero estamos trabajando con un diccionario que no lo permite.

Lo que sí se puede hacer es crear una comprensión de la estructura que solo contemple los casos cuya clave este dentro del rango. Por ejemplo:

```
for key in [k for k in niveles if k in range(6,9)]:
    print(key)
```

Ten en cuenta que por los valores que esperas recuperar `(6,7,8)`,`range()` debe invocarse desde el 6 hasta el 9 (no incluido).

Answer (score 1):

Una operación como `niveles[5:8]` se transforma en:

```
niveles[slice(5,8,None)]
```

que a su vez se transforma en:

```
niveles.__getitem__(slice(5,8,None))
```

O sea, se usa el mismo mecanismo para acceder a un elemento que para acceder a un rango.

El problema es que los diccionarios no son secuencias, por lo que carecen de operador `slice`. No se puede asumir ningún orden en los elementos de un diccionario a pesar de que, a partir de python 3.6, los diccionarios conserven el orden de las entradas, ya que podría cambiar en implementaciones futuras. Si quieres conservar el orden de las entradas hay que usar *diccionarios ordenados* (`OrderedDict`), pero el problema sería el mismo ya que los diccionarios ordenados tampoco tienen definido el operador `slice`.

Buscando un modo de implementar esta operación, podemos probar con el operador de iteradores `islice` aplicado a las claves del diccionario:

```
from itertools import islice

for key in islice(niveles, 5, 8):
    print(key)
```

Aquí muestra los elementos introducidos en las posiciones 5, 6 y 7, pero insisto en que no tiene porqué corresponder con las clave 5, 6 ó 7. Coincide porque es así como se ha generado el diccionario, en orden de clave. Si se crea el diccionario en otro orden, saldría otro resultado.

Para tener más control, podemos crear nuestro propio diccionario, para lo que seremos nosotros quienes tenemos que interpretar qué hacer con el rango.

Por ejemplo, siguiendo con el ejemplo de `itertools.islice` anterior:

```
class MyDict(dict):

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return (islice(self, item.start, item.stop, item.step)
                if isinstance(item, slice)
                else super().__getitem__(item))
```

Esta clase `MyDict` es una especialización de diccionario. Si le enviamos un rebanado (eg: `niveles[5:8]`), devuelve un iterador `islice`; en caso contrario se comporta como un diccionario estándar.

Nos permite trabajar del siguiente modo:

```
d = MyDict(niveles)

for key in d[5:10:2]:
   print(key)
```

Resultado: 5, 7, 9

Por supuesto, la clase `MyDict` se podría mejorar para asegurar que las claves de los elementos pertenezcan al rango solicitado:

```
class MyDict2(dict):

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, slice):
           rang = range(*item.indices(len(self)))
           return {k:v for (k,v) in self.items() if k in rang}
        else:
           super().__getitem__(item)

d = MyDict2(niveles)

for key in d[5:10:2]:
   print(key)
```

Resultado: 5, 7, 9

Destacar que esta implementación, `MyDict2`, sería bastante más robusta, pudiendo hacer cualquier operación de rangos, por ejemplo:

```
for key in d[-2:]:
    print(key)
```

Resultado: 19, 20

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaría mirar 'dict.items' de python, que itera en un diccionario en pares de key-value, y puede ser útil. Te pongo un ejemplo:

```
>>> niveles = {0: 0, 1: 50}
>>> for key, value in niveles.items():
...   print key, value
0 0
1 50
```